# Cleanup make results

Tags: sudo, make

I just executed `make xy` with the wrong user (root). If I try to execute `make xy` with the correct user (non-root) I get some errors: file z already exists etc. A `sudo make xy` has no effect. How can I "revert" a make to delete all these files and create a "innocent" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [clean](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/make/make.html#SEC31) target?

```
make clean
```

Comment: No, because I didn't know this command :) I'll try this!

Comment: "Nothing to do for the target 'make'"... so it doesn't work

Comment: You have to run it as root again, just like the "wrong" one before.

Comment: If it thought that `make` was the target, rather than `clean`, then you didn't run the command properly.

Comment: Also as root executed the same "nothing to do..."

Comment: The error is somewhere else so your answer was right for my question :-)

Comment: what was the error?